# Show that $G= \langle x,y\mid x^2,xyx^{-1}y=e \rangle$ is a semidirect product of two of its subgroups

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, semidirect-product

Show that $G= \langle x,y\mid x^2,xyx^{-1}y=e \rangle$ is a semidirect product of two of its subgroups

---

my first attempt was to use the theorem: $G\cong H\rtimes K$ iff $H=$ normal $H\cap K=\{e\}$ and $G=HK$

but I can't show if one of them $(H=\langle y\rangle ,K=\langle x\rangle)$ is normal and also can't show $G=HK$

the hint I get is to take $H=\langle y\rangle ,K=\langle x\rangle$ and $f:K\rightarrow \text{Aut(H)}$

$f(x)=\phi_x$ where $\phi_x(y)=xyx^{-1}=y^{-1}$

I am confused about what I should show with this hint.

Clearly $f $ is a homomorphism, if I take the product $(h,k)(h',k')=(hf(k)h,kk')$ how can I show that  $G\cong H\rtimes K$. Can someone explain, this topic is fairly confusing.

Comment: Your group is the cyclic group of order $2$, because if $xyx^{-1}=e$ then $y=e$. I suspect you have the wrong presentation. Perhaps it was $xyx^{-1}y=e$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin this is what my book writes, maybe it's a typo, I don't know. I am still learning about the topic, cant say I know what I am doing with confidence.

Comment: It's definitely a typo. The group as you have written it is cyclic of order $2$. The only way to express the cyclic group of order $2$ as a semidirect product is as itself semidirect product the trivial group, or the trivial group semidirect product itself.

Comment: If the hint says $\phi_x(y)=xyx^{-1}=y^{-1}$, you will deduce $xyx^{-1}y=e$

Comment: The hint suggests that you are supposed to have $xyx^{-1}=y^{-1}$, or $xyx^{-1}y=e$, as I guessed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin my question here is what should I do in order to show that $G\cong H\rtimes  K$

Comment: And what I'm saying is that, as written, your problem doesn't even make sense. So you need to fix the statement before it makes sense, which needs to happen before anyone can tell you how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group presentation is the standard presentation of the infinite dihedral group $\langle a,b\mid a^2=1, aba=b^{-1}\rangle$. In that group $H=\langle b\rangle$ is normal and infinite cyclic, $K=\langle a\rangle$ is of order $2$. Thus $H\cap K=\{e\}$ and $HK$ is the whole group, as required.